# Freemarker template (FTL) not working in struts2

Tags: spring, struts2, web.xml

I am working with Struts2 and ftl. Instead of jsp I want to use ftl, but when I define welcome file in web.xml as login.ftl it is not working. It just shown as text. The entire code is shown in the browser, but if it is jsp everything works.

I just paste my web.xml below.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.ftl</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

How can I configure ftl in Struts2? If I use that same page as output page of an action it is working. How can I solve this? Is there any problem with my web.xml configuration?? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if anybody knows the answer please reply. i really appreciate your help.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this help you(extract of a web.xml):

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.thoughtequity.video.web.servlet.SiteFreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>

  <!-- FreemarkerServlet settings: -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>NoCache</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>ContentType</param-name>
    <param-value>text/html</param-value>
  </init-param>

  <!-- FreeMarker settings: -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>template_update_delay</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value> <!-- 0 is for development only! Use higher value otherwise. -->
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>number_format</param-name>
    <param-value>0.##########</param-value>
  </init-param>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Action Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/te.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    


<!-- Map *.ftl files to Freemarker-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    

<!-- The Welcome File List -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.vm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker template files need to be processed in order to generate textual pages that shows your data. You cannot just put them in `welcome-file-list`. For example in Struts2 you can redirect to your action and there use your template.

Also read this http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/HowToUseAServletAsYourMainWebPage.